# Create a branch in Subversion where one directory one directory from trunk is never updated?

Tags: svn, branch

In my trunk I have 2 directories ..

/dev/
and
/qa/

I want to create a branch from trunk (head) where whenever I merge trunk changes into branch:
- I get the latest version of /dev/  .. but ...
- /qa/ does NOT get updated, i.e. it's fixed to the original version that I checked out.

Is there a simply way of doing this ? I know that in other SCM's i.e. Clearcase, I can change versions of directories to be checkout to fixed versions (instead of head).

Maybe the use of SVN:Externals somehow?

or somehow forcing SVN to only "record" merges for /qa/.

Note that I would like to refrain from changing any of the structure of trunk ... i.e. moving the /qa/ directory somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Two thoughts;

- Use a [Tag](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.tags.html) for your QA branch. Good if you don't need to check in updates.
- Use a Branch for your QA work and leave your Dev on the trunk. Then you can keep working, and merge bug fixes back to the trunk as needed.

Check out [Common Branching Patterns](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.commonpatterns.html) in the SVN docs for more information.

Comment: Can I tell my branch to pull /qa/ from a tag , but /dev/ from trunk .. Assuming of course that they are in the same directory (in svn).

Comment: What I would do is have one directory for the `/qa/` tag (or branch) then another directory for `/dev/`. In this way you keep them both separate and can make changes in parallel. For example, our trunk is the latest, and we do development branches. We also have Tags for QA, Production, etc. We can always get back to a QA branch by pulling that tag.

Comment: So basically I would have to change the directory structure of my current trunk .. i.e. move /qa/ out separately?

Comment: If I understand your requirements; Your repo would have a single `/dev/` tree. You'd then create a `qa` branch. For day to day work, on your HD, you'd checkout the QA branch into `/prj/qa` and the trunk (dev) into `/prj/dev` and off you go.

Comment: It's a definitely a possible solution ... though I was hoping for something more seamless for developers. In Clearcase for example, I would only need to modify the config spec to make an exception for the /qa/ directory to explicitly use an older version.